# How to open Windows Powershell (Elevated) without admin rights?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to turn on The Windows Subsystem for Kali Linux. But it requires me to execute powershell as admin.

This is for executing a command on my pc. I have tried task scheduler but it did not work.

Comment: Your question is asking how to be administrator without being administrator. The answer is that you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

An "elevated" Command Prompt or Powershell session is, in fact, a session with admin rights. If you do not have credentials that grant you admin rights on the system, you cannot open an elevated session. There is no way to circumvent this. Talk to whoever is the administrator of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a line in the PS to elevate the commands?

```
# Set the variable
$cred = Get-Credential -credential domain\privaccount$
```

then depending on the comment, add

```
 -credential $cred
```

For example:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -credential domain\MyAdmin$

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -credential $cred
```

What command are you trying to run elevated?

Comment: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux